# Highcharts bar with non-stacked percent series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create Highcharts bar chart with non-stacked percentage values.

I use:

```
plotOptions.bar.stacking = 'percent'
```

But this stack all series on top another to get to 100%. I want each series to be rendered as different bar.

I there any way doing it other than processing series data myself?

Comment: You need to preprocess data on your own.

Comment: Was afraid to hear that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you've specified there is how you want the chart to stack the bars, specifically.

To see labels/tooltips, etc as % of total, you'll need to loop through the data and calculate it all.

Then you use the formatters to output the right values for the axis labels, the tooltip, the data labels, etc

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/320/

Comment: Thanx! I was hoping for a configuration solution but I guess I'll do it as you've stated...

Comment: Having something built in to handle this would be nice, and - it would seem - fairly trivial to implement.  You might suggest it on Highcharts' feature request site: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general