# How to display percent of all series total as a stackLabel on stacked bar chart in highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am needing to display stackLabels on the stacked bar chart as both a total of the stack and a percent of the total. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506058/highcharts-bar-with-non-stacked-percent-series)  gives a version of the answer I am looking for, but the data var they declare at the beginning of the code is hardcoded data, whereas I will need it to be dynamic. Additionally, I have several series I am dealing with that all need to be summed together (example below just uses two). I think the main thing I am missing is how to reference associated data from JS code to sum over it? I am very unfamiliar with JS.

For the example code and plot below, I want the stackLabels to say '30(30%)' for a, '20(20%)' for b, '50(50%)' for a. (If it was a different data set of 10, 20, and 30 it would be '10(17%)' for a, '20(33%)' for b, '30(50%)' for c since the total across everything would be 60.)

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(z = c(20,4,6,8,25),
                y = c(3,3,2,4,25),
                x = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'))
df <- df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(y = sum(y), z = sum(z), total = sum(y,z))
df

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = as.factor(unique(df$x))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$y, name = 'y', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$z, name = 'z', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_yAxis(stackLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

[Test Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDoL5.png)

Based on the linked question above, I am thinking I need to alter the code to add a loop sum, but am not sure how to finish it.

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = as.factor(unique(df$x))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$y, name = 'y', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$z, name = 'z', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_yAxis(stackLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, 
                              formatter = JS("function() {var data = *reference to the data*;
                                                          var dataSum = 0;
                                                          for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
                                                              dataSum += data[i]
                                                          }
                                                          var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100;
                                                          return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                                                      }"))) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

Please advise. Still new to stack overflow so let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Revised answer as OP appears to want each stack label to show the subtotal as a proportion of all stacks as well as the N.

I added some more random data to the set. The main thing is to include the total across every series. Then you can use that number within `formatter` to divide the stack totals.

```
df <- data.frame(
  z = c(20,4,26,8,25,10),
  y = c(3,10,2,34,25,41),
  x = c('a','a','b','b','c','c')
)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(y = sum(y), z = sum(z), sub_total = sum(y,z)) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(sub_total))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = as.factor(unique(df$x))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$y, name = 'y', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$z, name = 'z', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_yAxis(stackLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
    formatter = JS(paste0("function() {
      var prop = this.total / ", unique(df$total) ," * 100
      prop = Highcharts.numberFormat(prop)
      return this.total + ' (' + prop + '%)';
    }")))) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

[image]

---

**Prev Answer**

I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

> I am needing to display stackLabels on the stacked bar chart as both a total of the stack and a percent of the total.

It would seem to me that "% of the total" should always equal 100% if you're taking the sum of all series, e.g. total/total = 1. However, maybe I'm missing something here.

In any case, the following code will replicate the stack labels you're looking for. Where `this.total` represents the total of each stacked item.

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = 'column') %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = as.factor(unique(df$x))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$y, name = 'y', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_add_series(df$z, name = 'z', stack = 'stack') %>% 
  hc_yAxis(stackLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
    formatter = JS("function() {
      return this.total + '(' + this.total + '%)'             
    }"))) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realized I had not put together the correct data set to display what I was wanting (I put 40 instead of 50 for c so that the total didn't add up to 100). I have made edits to reflect it correctly.

The code you provided just makes same number a percent, when actually I need it as a percent of the total - see my edits for an example. If the numbers stayed as before, the total would be 30+20+40 = 90, so I would want to display 30(33%), 20(22%), 40(44%). Hope that clarifies, sorry for the confusing post.

Comment: @passer_days - I updated my answer. Let me know if that is more inline with what you're looking for.